# Finding all the ten different digits in a random string

Tags: regex, pcre

Sorry if this is answered somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

I need to write a `regexp` to matches on strings that contain the digits from 0 to 9 exactly once. For example:

```
e8v5i0l9ny3hw1f24z7q6
```

You can see that numbers [0-9] are present exactly once and in random order. *(Letters are present also exactly once, but that is an advanced quest...)* It must not match if a digit is missing or if any digit is present more than one time.

So what would be the best regexp to match on strings like these? I am still learning `regex` and couldn't find a solution. It is PCRE, running in perl environment, but I cannot use perl, only the regex part of it. Sorry for my english and thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sure that there are much better ways to solve this rather than using regex.

Comment: Do you want one regexp or ten regexps with and operators would be ok too? :)

Comment: Can you sort the string?

Comment: What do you mean by sorting? I can not alter the string in any way.:( Maybe one regexp is better than ten with and operators.:) But I am curious of the latter, can you show?

Comment: If you can have a sorted string, you can then look for .*0.*1.*2.*...

Comment: Classic case of using a hammer to crack a nut. There are simple and clear ways to this. Regular expressions aren't one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this pattern to verify the string:

```
^\D*(?>(\d)(?!.*\1)\D*){10}$
```

- `^\D*` Starts with any amount of characters, that are no digit
- `(?>(\d)(?!.*\1)\D*){10}` followed by 10x: a digit (captured in first capturing group), if the captured digit is not ahead, followed by any amount of `\D` non-digits, using a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So 10x a digit, with itself not ahead consecutive should result in 10 different `[0-9]`.

`\d` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[0-9]`, `\D` is the negation `[^0-9]`

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jE1xQ4), [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3110638)

---

If you need the digit-string then, just extract the digits, e.g. php ([test eval.in](https://eval.in/136287))

```
$str = "e8v5i0l9ny3hw1f24z7q6";

$pattern = '/^\D*(?>(\d)(?!.*\1)\D*){10}$/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $str)) {
  echo preg_replace('/\D+/', "", $str);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work as I think it should work! At least at debuggex.com says so. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to create a regular expression that matches one specific permutations of the numbers and ingnore the other characters. E.g.

```
^[^\d]*0[^\d]1[^\d]*2[^\d]*3[^\d]*4[^\d]*5[^\d]*6[^\d]*7[^\d]*8[^\d]*9[^\d]*$
```

You can combine 10! expressions for every possible permutation with |

Although this is completely inpractical it shows that such a **regular** expression (without lookahead) is indeed possible.

However this is something that is much better done without regular expression matching.

Comment: you can use lookaheads.You dont need all 10*9*8*7... permutations

Comment: Yes of course, but as I understand it lookahead is an extension. Strictly speaking this is then not a reuglar expression anymore.

Comment: But with this you determine the order of the numbers, so they cannot be in random order.

Comment: That's why I wrote that it would require 10! expressions of this type.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "e8v5i0l9ny3hw1f24z7q6";
$s = preg_replace('/[^\d]/i', '', $s); //remove non digits
if(strlen($s) == 10) //do we have 10 digits ?
if (!preg_match('/(\d)(\1+)/i', $s))  //if no repeated digits
echo "String has 10 different digits";
```

http://ideone.com/eY4eGx